# Are header-only libraries more efficient?

Tags: c++, c, libraries

Assumptions

1. One of the advantages of header-only libraries for C++ is that they do not need to be compiled separately.
2. In C and C++ `inline` makes sense only if the function is **defined** in a header file*.
3. Traditionally, in C, .c/.h layout has been used, where the header represents the minimal public interface of the translation unit. Similarly, .cpp/hpp.

Question

Are header-only libraries generally more efficient code- and execution time wise than the traditional layout? If so, is this because of extensive inlining or other optimizations?

<sub>* - defining the function in a header allows the compiler to see the implementation during compilation of any translation unit and practically makes inlining code possible</sub>

Comment: You'd be surprised how well a lot of modern C++ linkers (GCC, MSVC, ICC, etc) can inline code across separate translation units. I would say "generally no" on the efficiency perspective given the number of times optimizing linkers defied my expectations and managed to inline anyway (that's excluding dylib contexts where inlining in a header or providing the implementation in a separate statically-linked library can help). Yet header-only libraries, provided that they are stable in both interface and implementation, can be sexy because of how easily they can be deployed in new projects.

Comment: I don't know that this deserves a full answer, but one huge benefit of header only libs is the ease of installation and usage: Download, #include "lib.h(pp)", done.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174657/when-are-header-only-libraries-acceptable

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> One of the advantages of header-only libraries for C++ is that they do not need to be compiled separately

No, that is not an advantage, quite the opposite - the main part of the library has to be compiled as often as it gets included, not just once. That will typically increase compile times. However, if you are referring to the advantages listed [here in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header-only): that article is talking about decreased administrative overhead concerning the whole build, packaging and deployment process.

> In C and C++ inline makes sense only if the function is defined in a header file*

This depends on the compiler/linker system, but I guess for most existing C and C++ compilers this is true.

> Traditionally, in C, .c/.h layout has been used, where the header represents the minimal public interface of the translation unit. Similarly, .cpp/hpp.

That is mostly correct. C++ class headers often contain more than the minimal public interface - they typically contain also a lot of private stuff. To mitigate this, things like the [PIMPL idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom) are used. This is something like "the opposite" of a header-only library, it tries to minimize the necessary header content.

But to answer your main question: this is a trade-off. The more library code one puts into the header files, the more the compiler has **a chance** for optimizing the code for speed (if this really happens, or if the increasement is noteable, is a completely different question). On the other hand, too much code in headers increases the compile time. Especially in large C++ projects this can become a serious problem, see ["Large Scale C++ Software Design" by John Lakos](https://books.google.de/books?id=AuMpAQAAMAAJ) - though the book is a little bit outdated and some of the problems described in there are addressed by modern compilers, the general ideas/solutions are still valid.

In particular, when you are not using a stable (third party) library, but you are developing your own libs during your project, the compile times become apparent. Everytime you change something in the lib, you must change a header file, which will cause a recompile and linkage of all dependent units.

IMHO the popularity of header-only libs is caused by the popularity of template meta programming. For most compilers, templated libs *must* be header-only because the compiler can only start the main compile process when the type parameters are provided, and for full compilation and optimization the compiler must see "both at once" - the library code plus the template parameter values. That makes it impossible (or at least hard) to produce any "precompiled" compilation units for such a library.

Comment: So in short, header-only libraries are more *convenient* rather than more *efficient*; and since C++ does not have any standard package manager, this helps driving adoption.

Comment: @MatthieuM: no, the compiled code may indeed sometimes be more efficient, and for template libs the header-only design is typically not a question of convenience. And increased compiled times are definitely not more convenient.

Comment: Having the hot code in the headers might indeed lead to a more efficient compiled code, however this does not require having *all* the code in headers and is therefore independent, IMHO, from header-only libraries.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: that is surely correct, nethertheless I think the term "more convenient" does not describe the case well.

Comment: It is convenient that you don't have to worry what compile flags were used for the library.

Comment: @Vorac: don't play with words.  Surely there are things that are more convenient in header-only libraries. Other's things are clearly less convenient (like compile times or that one must open-source such a library in full). But  Matthieu's comment was saying "header-only libs are more convenient" (in general!) than other libs, and his statement about efficiency is wrong in this generality, too. That's what the comments above are about.

Comment: I worked on a large embedded project on top of a slimmed-down, older OS for my previous employer, and in those cases I can attest to the pain of long compile times.  Anyone caught stuffing too much into header files would be dealt with mercilessly.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to reduce dependencies by proper interfaces so that compile time is bearable. In a header only library or in a (near to) header only executable. And reducing dependencies is a good thing anyways ...

Comment: Hm. Doesn't LTO have all the potential efficiency-advantages of having things in the header, without the downsides?

Comment: The biggest disadvantage is that you don't have a file that describes the public interface and nothing else.

Comment: @gnasher729: it may be debatable if this is "the biggest" disadvantage, but I guess using a tool like doxygen can balance this (AFAIK even if the code is not annotated with specific doxygen comments, this might be useful).

Answer (score 17):

Well, let's first demolish some of your assumptions:

> 1. One of the advantages of header-only libraries for C++ is that they do not need to be compiled separately.

Compiling things separately means potentially not having to recompile everything if only a part changes.
So, a disadvantage instead of an advantage.

> 2. In C and C++ inline makes sense only if the function is defined in a header file*.

Yes, the only effect `inline` has left is the exception to the [one-definition-rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onedefinitionrule).
Woe unto you if those definitions are different in any way though.

So, if a function is internal to a compilation-unit, mark it `static`. That also makes inlining more likely, as the function needs to be available in order to inline it.
Still, take a look at link-time-optimization, as supported by at least MSVC++, gcc and clang.

> 3. Traditionally, in C, .c/.h layout has been used, where the header represents the minimal public interface of the translation unit. Similarly, .cpp/hpp.

Well, only presenting the minimal interface is certainly one of the goals, to achieve higher API and ABI stability, and to minimize compilation times.

Especially C++ classes aren't really geared to that though, as all the private bits leak into the header, as do the protected ones whether you want to derive from it or not.

The design-pattern [PIMPL](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/213259/whats-is-the-point-of-pimpl-pattern-while-we-can-use-interface-for-the-same-pur) is for reducing such details.

The part where separating interface and implementation completely fails in C++ is templates though.
The committee tried to do something with [exported templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416872/using-export-keyword-with-templates), but that has been abandoned as too complicated and not really working.

Now, they are working on [a proper module system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25621565/3204551), though it's slow going. That severely reduce compile-times, and should also increase API and ABI stability by decreasing their surface.

> Are header-only libraries generally more efficient code- and execution time wise than the traditional layout? If so, is this because of extensive inlining or other optimizations?

Header-only libraries can be more efficient in code-size and execution-time, though that depends on whether the library is shared, how much of it is used, in what ways, and whether inlining proves a decisive win in that specific case.

And the reason inlining is so important for optimization isn't because inlining itself is such a great boost, but due to the opportunities for constant-propagation and further optimization it opens.

Answer (score 0):

**Inlining can be done by Link Time Optimization (LTO)**

I'd like to highlight this since it decreases the value of this commonly cited advantage of header only libraries ("you need definitions on a header to inline").

A minimal concrete example of this is shown at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046547/link-time-optimization-and-inline/61367211#61367211

So you just pass a flag, and inlining can be done across object files without any refactoring work, no need to keep definitions in headers for that anymore.

LTO might have its own downsides too however: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736507/is-there-a-reason-why-not-to-use-link-time-optimization-lto